# Error when installing package ‘openNLPmodels.en’ in R / RStudio. Error: cannot open URL 'http://datacube.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds'

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, opennlp

When I try to install package ‘openNLPmodels.en’ in RStudio I get the following error messages:
I run the latest versions of RStudio an R. openNLP and openNLPdata are correctly installed. Can you help me to install the package? Thank you very much in advance.

```
install.packages("openNLPmodels.en", dependencies=TRUE, repos    = 
"http://datacube.wu.ac.at/", type = "source", INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))


Warning in install.packages :
 cannot open URL 'http://datacube.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
trying URL 'http://datacube.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/openNLPmodels.en_1.5-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 77794529 bytes (74.2 MB)
downloaded 74.2 MB

'\\WWG00M.ROOTDOM.NET\DFS\HOME\wt2rrib'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
ERROR: unable to create '\\Wwg00m.rootdom.net/dfs/HOME/WT2RRIB/R/Sentimental Analysis/openNLPmodels.en'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘openNLPmodels.en’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Try `install.packages("openNLP", repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at/", type = "source")`

Comment: openNLP is already successfully installed. Facing problem in installing openNLPmodels.en

Comment: it seems your real problem is around `ERROR: unable to create '\\Wwg00m.rootdom.net/dfs/HOME/WT2RRIB/R/Sentimental Analysis/openNLPmodels.en'`, rather than the warning from the question title

Comment: I am unable to find a way around.

Comment: It seems, the source is quite old: https://datacube.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/. Perhaps contact the maintainers. I also can't install the the package.

Comment: I am very new to R. Can you tell me please how to contact maintainers?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not installing openNLP. The problem is about manually installing the accompanying corpus in the language of your choice. Here are the options for the different languages in https://datacube.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/

openNLPmodels.da_1.5-2.tar.gz

openNLPmodels.de_1.5-2.tar.gz

openNLPmodels.en_1.5-1.tar.gz

openNLPmodels.es_1.5-1.tar.gz

openNLPmodels.it_1.5-1.tar.gz

openNLPmodels.nl_1.5-2.tar.gz

openNLPmodels.pt_1.5-2.tar.gz

openNLPmodels.sv_1.5-2.tar.gz

In your question, you are choosing English, so download the following onto your localhost: https://datacube.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/openNLPmodels.en_1.5-1.tar.gz

Manually install it into RStudio by selecting the tar.gz option:

[image: Install from GUI]

Now you've got the English corpus installed for text mining with openNLP.